# The CSS local() function is invalid

Tags: css

I used the `local()` function to refer to a font on the client machine on the `src` attribute value position of CSS `@font-Face` rule. Either I changed the font name in the argument to an upper case with no Spaces or other forms would not work properly, such as `Hiragino Sans GB W3`,`Hiragino Sans GB`,`HiraginoSansGB-Regular`,`HiraginoSansGB Regular`,`HiraginoSansGB Normal`, but writing `Hiragino Sans GB` directly on the property value position of `font-family` works.

Could you please tell me what's going on here? Thank you.

Comment: Add some of your sample code.

Comment: The code is scattered and not easy to add....